# Not finding the Correct xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying write a Python script to get some information from Google's products listed on the top right of the screen. (Usual 6 pictures with price and seller)

I am using Python, PhantomJS and Selenium

Doing a google search for "red shoe" I want my script to return the prices. I get stuck in the step where I try to even find the element containing the products. Am I missing something with my xpath?

```
    def getTopSongs(object):
    print "Working YETI"
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('c:/projects/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe')
    browser.get('http://google.com/search?q=red+shoe')
    time.sleep(5)
    title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains@class, "pla-unit")]/text()[contains(., "red")]/following::b').text
```

From Google's webpage I element under a few nested

```
<div id="rhs">
...
 <div class="_Pwb">
  <div class="_Ohb">
   <div style="width:109px" class="pla-unit">
    <div class="_PD">
     <div class="pla-unit-img-container">
     <div class="_Z5">
       <div class="_vT"><a href="http://www.somewebsite.com">
         <span class="rhsl4">Nina 'Forbes' Peep Toe Pump <b>Red</b> R...</span>
         <span class="rhsg3 rhsl5">Nina 'Forbes' Peep Toe Pum...</span>
         <span class="rhsg4">Nina 'Forbes' Peep Toe Pu...</span></a>
       </div>
       <div class="_QD"><b>$78.95</b></div>
       <div class="_mC">
         <span class="rhsl4 a">Nordstrom</span>
         <span class="rhsg3 rhsl5 a">Nordstrom</span>
         <span class="rhsg4 a">Nordstrom</span>
       </div>
      </div>
```

*Update:
I added more HTML. In this example I am looking to get the text from  ($78.95) annd  (Norstrom)

*Update
To clarify,

```
<div id="rhs">
```

is an unique element

There are however multiple (6) elements of:

```
<div style="width:109px" class="pla-unit">
```

The elements under each category have the same name and follow the same structure and substructures
ie, there are 6

```
 <div class="_PD">
  <div class="pla-unit-img-container">
 <div class="_Z5">
  <div class="_vD">
  <div class="_QD">
  <div class="_mC">
```

and so on.

The main objective is to get all of the elements but for purposes of debugging I was asking help to get the first one.

The xpath for a price unit using XPathChecker on Firefox is:
    id('rhs_block')/x:div[1]/x:div/x:div/x:div/x:div[1]/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:div[2]/x:b

Comment: Can you show more HTML? What exactly comes after the `div[@class='pl-unit']?`

Comment: Your XPath is bad. A `text()` node does not have children.

Comment: @SiKing The path expression does not look for children of text nodes. `following::` is another axis than `child::`.

Comment: Better now, but it is still unclear what the rules are. For instance: is the `class` attribute of span (e.g. `span/@class='rhs14`) unique? Are you looking for the first `span` element that comes after `div[@pla-unit]` that has a `b` child element that in turn contains "Red"? Is the price always in the `div` that comes immediately afterwards? Is the brand name always in a span where the `class` attribute is the same as the span that contained "Red", plus an " a" (e.g. "rsh14 a")?

Comment: The structure is the same, I am looking for the <b> information under <div class='_QD"> as well as the text inside <div class ='mC'> <span class="rhs14 a"> TEXT </span>

Answer (score 0):

You can use ancestor:: to go back up then following-sibling:: to get elements at the same level that follow it.

I haven't tried this but give it a shot:

```
title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains@class, "pla-unit")]/text()[contains(., "red")]/ancestor::div/following-sibling::div[1]').text
```

Then to get to your div class ='mC' you just change:

```
following-sibling::div[1]
```

to

```
following-sibling::div[2]
```

and get the text from the spans under that.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, It is still not working. I am getting a "Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //...

Comment: I think it just can't find the "pla-unit" and thus can't move forward